# How to set Visual Studio Code to prepend a comment character when splitting a commented line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know why this stopped working, but not so long ago, if I had long comment line and I hit `return` when the cursor is in the middle of that line somewhere, Visual Studio Code used to both indent the new line the same and insert a new comment character. It stopped doing that. Usually, the line is indented correctly (though sometimes, it has started over-indenting), but it never inserts the comment character anymore.

I tried searching the settings for this behavior (and googled it), but I cannot figure out how to restore this behavior...

*UPDATE*: I learned today that the comment charater (and a space) are in fact added, but something (perhaps an extension?) is actually reverting the modification and deleting the `#` . I discovered this because if I *undo* (to remove the line break I added) it replaces the `#`  first. I have to undo again to remove the line break I'd added.

How do I debug this? Is there a log of automatic actions applied to what I've entered so that I can see what is removing the auto-comment? If it helps, from my googling, it seems that maybe the setting that is supposed to add the `#`  is `val.vscode-continue-inline-comments`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I *think* I figured it out.

I opened all of the settings files with:

```
open -e `\find ~/.vscode/ -name "settings*"`
```

and skimmed their contents.  On a hunch, I suspected *(but I was wrong...)*:

```
~/.vscode//extensions/ms-python.python-2024.0.0/pythonFiles/lib/jedilsp/jedi/settings.py
```

So I searched the settings in VS Code for `jedi` and I discovered:

[image]

I changed the Python Language Server setting from "Default" to <s>"None"</s> *"Jedi"* and then the expected behavior of `vscode-continue-inline-comments` resumed.  Now when I hit enter in the middle of a comment line, the new line is correctly indented and the comment & space remain.  Undoing also goes back to before having hit enter.

I did encounter a downside, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Changing the setting to `Pylance` caused me to lose various features (like the "Rename Symbol" option in context menus).  Changing it to "Jedi" fixed the split-comment-line behavior *and* kept the extra features like "Rename Symbol".  I searched through the Pylance settings and could not find anything that caused the comment editing behavior to go awry.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @TylerH. I tend toward stream of consciousness and probably shouldn't.

Comment: Mostly, the issue I saw is that edits should just update the content. If users are interested in what you had said in previous iterations, they can see the revision history of the post (which is public for everyone). :-) No need for strikethroughs or "EDIT" callouts, etc.

Comment: I still am not back to normal. I was missing some syntax highlighting, so I tried all the settings.  Returning to "Default" brings back everything else except for the comment splitting behavior.  I'm going to deselect this as being the answer.  Ugh.